# Shell Command 'join' not working

Tags: linux, shell, join, command-line

I am trying to join 2 sorted simple file, but for some strange reason, its not working.

f1.txt:

```
f1 abc
f2 mno
f3 pqr
```

f2.txt

```
abc a1
mno a2
pqr a3
```

Command:

```
join -t '\t' f1.txt f2.txt -1 2 -2 1 > f3.txt
```

FYI in f1, f2 the space is actually a tab.
I don't know why this is not working. F3.txt is forming empty.
Please provide any valuable insights.

Comment: `man join` ? ;-) Good luck.

Comment: Since you are new here, see [What does it mean when an answer is "accepted"?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)

Answer (score 2):

Using `bash` `join` on 2nd column of 1st file and 1st column on 2nd file

```
$ join -1 2 -2 1 file1 file2 > file3
$ cat file3
abc f1 a1
mno f2 a2
pqr f3 a3
```

Also `join` by default de-limits on tab-space characters. The `man` page of `join` says the following about the `-t` flag.

```
-t CHAR
     use CHAR as input and output field separator. 
     Unless -t CHAR is given, leading blanks separate fields and are ignored,
```